# Nature of curve based on second derivative alone

Tags: calculus

Consider a function $y(x)$ such that

$$y(x) = Ay^{"}(x)$$

for all $x$. Here A is a positive constant.

Given that we have no information about the first derivative, is  it possible for $y(x)$ to have both positive and negative values ?

Comment: $y=\sinh (x/\sqrt{A})$, for example.

Answer (score 0):

If you switch variables, you have
$$-A\frac{x''}{[x']^3}=y$$ Reduction of order $p=x'$ gives
$$p=\pm\frac{\sqrt{A}}{\sqrt{y^2+ c_1}} \implies x+c_2=\pm \sqrt{A} \log \left(\sqrt{y^2+c_1}+y\right)$$ that you can easily inverse (but the $\pm$ remains).